# The container ivy.xml references non existing library

Tags: eclipse, ivy

I'm new to Ivy, but am working on a project with multiple dependencies.

I'm publishing some jar's locally, and just came across the following error:

> The container ivy.xml references non existing library

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had multiple projects open in Eclipse, and one of the other projects I was trying to build had unresolved Ivy dependencies.

So to solve it, I basically just right clicked on the project and chose "**Ivy | Resolve**".

Answer (score 0):

Adding junit **dependency** to **ivy.xml** may solve your problem :

`<dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.11"/>`

And then you should **resolve ivy**.